# Google Play showing Nexus,Samsung and Motorola and some other devices as unsupported

Tags: android, android-manifest, multiple-apk

I tried uploading Multiple Apk in google play store, but it shows around 3000 devices in the unsupported list which include All Nexus and Moto Devices, and few Samsung high end devices.

Please suggest me some options to include these devices. Thanks in Advance.

Moto devices:
[image]

> **EDIT:**

Samsung Devices:
[image]

Nexus Devices:
[image]

**Phone Manifest:**

```
...
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
...
```

**Tablet Manifest:**

```
...
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
...
```

Comment: Post the contents of your `AndroidManifest.xml`, that will give some hints.

Comment: without manifest ? no way ...

Comment: @Trideep please post your AndroidManifest

Comment: how does google play store manage these devices support? how to give support for 1 apk in Phones only and other apk for tablets only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all section related to devices support in phone APK and add versionCode say `x`. By default, Phone APK will give support to all the devices. Now, give the **devices support details only in your tablet APK** while the versionCode of tablet APK must be `x+1`.

1. Change both the manifests as given below.
2. On play store, go to APK section of your app. Switch to Advanced mode.
3. Upload the phone APK (with lower versionCode say `x`) first and then upload the tablet APK (with higher versionCode say `x+1`).
4. Make sure that both these APKs that you uploaded are in `Activated` state.
5. Publish the app, and now you are happy to go.

**Phone Manifest:**

```
...
android:versionCode="x"
...
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<!--
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
-->
```

> For supporting the tablet only devices, you should refer [this section](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html) in android developer site.

**Tablet Manifest:**

```
...
android:versionCode="x+1"
...
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<!--
<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
-->
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I hope this answer might help you.